# umbraco and custom system table

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, system-tables

I have the following scenario:

My website db has a system table called "Companies", which includes an id field, companyName field, and companyImageUrl field.

How do I set up an umbraco document type for adding entries to this table ?

Maybe I shouldn't use a custom table at all ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Umbraco doesn't support what you want to do out of the box (mapping a document type to a table that isn't part of the umbraco core).

One approach that might work is to [create an action handler](http://umbracocms.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-and-using-action-handler.html) that syncs a Company doc type to your table when creating a node of that type.

It's a bit of a hack though.  I've found that I've very rarely *needed* to create custom tables.  What exactly are you trying to do with it?  My guess is that you don't really need it and would be better off working with a doc type instead.  Umbraco provides a variety of ways to get and act upon doc types from within custom C# code (check out the `umbraco.NodeFactory` namespace).  You'll also get the added benefit of being able to easily interact with these nodes from XSLT/Razor.